# Spring Boot scan of external libraries

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have multiple projects (non spring boot) with Spring Elements- `@RestController`.

I have one Spring boot main that uses these projects as dependencies and suppose to load their controllers at runtime.

However all Spring classes **outside the main project** are not being (scanned) loaded. I've tried using `@ComponentScan` `@EntityScan` with a base package, but it doesn't work. I guess that is because all of the classes I want to scan are not within the "`/BOOT-INF/classes`" but exists inside JAR files in the "`/BOOT-INF/lib`" folder within JAR files. Running the project from the IDE works when all projects exists in the workspace.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an "exec" configuration to the Spring-Boot-Maven-Plugin on each of the dependent projects fixed the issue:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
<classifier>exec</classifier>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```